# how to Add Progress Dialog in Service class?

Tags: android, android-service

I want to add Progress dialog Box in Service class. my apps is playing Radio live Streaming but apps load channel so i want to add progress dialog .when start radio progress dialog dismiss..have a Idea ?
Thanks in Advance..

```
public class MusicService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    public static MediaPlayer mediaplayer;
    String musicfile;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(" ibinder ", "");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", 0).show();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");

        mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", 0).show();
        Log.w(TAG, "onDestroy");
        mediaplayer.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "My Service Started :" + intent + " start id :" + startid, 0)
                .show();

        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        if (intent.getExtras().getString("paths") == null) {
            Log.i("Intent Null", "Null");
        } else {
            Log.i("Intent Not Null", "Not Null");
            musicfile = intent.getExtras().getString("paths");
            Log.i("musicfile", "" + musicfile);
            startPlayer();
            Log.i("startplayer() called","");
        }
    }

    public void startPlayer() {
        new Thread(startPlayer).start();
    }

    private Runnable startPlayer = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                mediaplayer.reset();
                mediaplayer.setDataSource(musicfile);
                mediaplayer.prepare();
                mediaplayer.start();
                Log.i("playchannel", musicfile);
                Log.e("Media Player Create", "player Create");
                Log.i("End startpayer called","");
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

this is my Service class and i want to play live radio streaming but live radio streaming take some load to play . so i want do something process when radio player take load some time.

Comment: Service does not have any UI, so you can't add any dialogs to it.

Comment: thanks.but one more question when mediaplayer start in service class it is load some time to play. so how to maintain this ?

Comment: I actually does not understand what you want.Do you have some interface for music selection?

Comment: i edit my question and write code here

Comment: try my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12346135/996493) might be helpful for you.

Comment: thanks. where i write this code ? Main activity or Service class ?

Comment: Service don't have UI, so you can use Notification or Activity to show progress

Comment: i already set this code in main Activity but i use intent to call service class and pass string via intent so when intent call, progress bar dismiss and some take load in service class..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thing you want stop progress dialog when mediaplayer start but media player start after take some time load radio channel so just progress dialog dismiss in service class using Main Activity object. like this

```
FMActivity.pDialogs.dismiss();
```

i thing its your problem solution.